# FILE I/O in C++ throws an error

Tags: c++, file-io

```
int main(array<System::String ^> ^args)
{

FILE* fp;
char str[1];
int x = 0;

fp = fopen("C:\\input.txt", "r");

do{
    x = fscanf(fp, "%s", str);

    if (x != -1)  // So that the last string is not printed twice
    {
        printf("%s ", str);
    }

  }while (x != -1);

return 0;

}
```

This program prints the correct output. BUT after printing, it throws an error in windows saying "Program stopped working". Also IF there is no text in the notepad file i.e if it is blank, then it shows no error. Please explain!

Comment: That declaration looks very C++ like to me.

Comment: This isn't C; it's C++. C doesn't have `array<System::string>`. First learn the name of the language you're using. :-) You're reading into memory that isn't big enough. You allocated `str[1]`, which is a single character, but you're reading far more data than that into it. You should probably stop using C file I/O in the first place, and start using the C++ functionality.

Comment: From that main function, this is not C.

Comment: Looks to be C++/CLI - although the actual code in question is basically C code.

Comment: @KenWhite It's not really C++ either.

Comment: @Cubic: Yeah, I'm not certain what it's supposed to be either. :-)

Comment: It is a .cpp file in C++ Console Project. But I have written a C code :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First off the statement of you main function looks very much like c++ not C.

Secondly from the statement `char str[1];` your declaring an array of characters that is of size 1. This means we can store 1 character inside this array so if we were to have `char str[128];` we could store 128 chars in it (Dont forget about the \0).

So this program is trying to read a string into your character array but after the first letter of the string it has no place to store the rest of the string which is why it crashes

Answer (score 2):

The trouble is that you have a `char` array of one byte that you are reading strings into.  You need to use an array that will be large enough to hold your largest piece of data.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But C and C++ do not have array boundary checking right?

Comment: Most C and C++ implementations don't have boundary checking.  But the code you wrote exhibits undefined behavior when it writes past the end of the array so the compiler is free to do whatever it wants, including cooking a pizza or printing your credit card number.  What is more likely to happen is that you will just be messing up some part of memory and it will screw up your program.

Comment: You're correct that they don't... but that's precisely why you are seeing corrupted data.